# What do the 3 different peer numbers represent in Parity?

Tags: parity, peers

My peer numbers in Parity are quite consistently at 0/25/25. What does each one of those numbers represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Active, connected, and currently configured minimum number of connections.

`<active> / <connected> / <min_configured>`

If you're seeing `0/25/25` it means that you have the minimum number of connections set by your configuration, but that the nodes you're connected to aren't active.

One thing you could do is try setting the minimum to a higher number to force it to open new connections which are, hopefully, more likely to be active.

`--min-peers NUM` (where `NUM` > 25)

Comment: Almost correct, except it is `<min_configured>` as in `--min-peers NUM`, also the highest number is not 50 (which is the default), you can set it to anything you like :)

Comment: Aha! Okay, I've always read the `help` strings in completely the wrong way. Makes complete sense now :-) Thanks!

Comment: Hold on :-) Are you sure? (I may have confused myself further... ) Looking at the Parity code, it *seems* to imply that it's a maximum value, rather than "try to maintain this minimum number of connections": [1](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/62158601fb55be616ccf4644958d3839f0ee20c2/js/src/api/format/output.js#L174), [2](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/f1e99ea2e40df59f4ea0b47a6c8a9f98840bdc1c/rpc/src/v1/types/sync.rs#L217), [3](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/blob/5fa088114c7eefddb10f8a37cd823b5191567654/js/src/redux/providers/statusReducer.js#L28)

Comment: @Richard Horrocks: What is meant by "active" in this situation?

Comment: @stone212 Here's an answer about "active".  https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/16064/active-vs-connected-peers