# "Active" vs. "Connected" Peers?

Tags: private-blockchain, parity, peers

I was reading this thread:
[What do the 3 different peer numbers represent in Parity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13816/what-do-the-3-different-peer-numbers-represent-in-parity)

And I realized that I don't understand the difference between active and connected regarding peers.

I have a private network I'm playing with, and three Parity nodes.  The readout on two of them is:

0/ 1/25

and the third:

0/ 2/25

I assume there is a firewall problem, but I also don't know how to get any of the 0s to be 1s or 2s.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Active versus connected is just a terminology question: *Active* means, they are actively synchronizing the chain, a `0` basically means you are already fully synchronized (or have no peers at all). *Connected* are all peers which you are listing to for new blocks and transactions, ideally this should be not `0`.

You say, you have two nodes with `0/1/25` and one with `0/2/25`, so your (virtual) peer-to-peer network looks like this:

```
[0/1/25] --- [0/2/25] --- [0/1/25]
```

So you have one node connected to the other two nodes, while they are not connected to a ring. Try to add all three `enode` addresses to a reserved peers file and pass this to all of your nodes:

```
--reserved-peers FILE          Provide a file containing enodes, one per line.
                               These nodes will always have a reserved slot on top
                               of the normal maximum peers. (default: None)
```

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  Also I did have a firewall problem.

Comment: @5chdn I am new to parity. Where should i do > --reserved-peers FILE One more, what does the keyword before 0/1/25 means

Comment: @learnlifelong on your terminal `parity --reserved-peers file.txt`.  And your other question is answered [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13816/what-do-the-3-different-peer-numbers-represent-in-parity?noredirect=1&lq=1).